# Topology of an orbit space constructed from a Fréchet space under the "local" action of some "smooth" group

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lie-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a nontrivial connected compact subgroup of the general linear group $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. For example, we may take $G$ to be $\operatorname{SO}(3)$.

Next, let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ be the space of smooth vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose components are real-valued Schwartz functions.

We then define the "local" action of $G$ on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ by
\begin{equation}
(A \cdot f)_j(x) :=\sum_{i=1}^3 A^i_j(x) f_i(x) \text{ for each } j \in \{1,2,3\}
\end{equation}
where $A(x):= \bigl( A^i_j(x) \bigr)_{i,j=1,2,3} : \mathbb{R}^3 \to G$ is an arbitrary smooth mapping with the superscript indexing the column / subscript indexing the row. Also, $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$.

It is well-known that $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a Fréchet space and $G$ is a Lie group. Now I wonder what topology the orbit space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3) / G$ has under the above "local" group action.

All textbook references on the group action and orbit space seem to deal with "global" actions of discrete groups only. I have looked for the keyword "orbifold" but that notion does not seem relevant to my question.

Could anyone please answer me or provide some relevant references?